# (node:7764) ExperimentalWarning: buffer.File is an experimental feature and might change at any time

Tags: javascript, discord

Sorry about my English,
I tried to code a discord bot that sends a captcha to the new member, and if the captcha is good my bot gives them a role, it works but after it gets the role my bot crash with this error message:
[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSjGF.png)
voici mon code :

```
const { Client, IntentsBitField, EmbedBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent, //IMPORTANT: make sure you enable "Message Content Intent" in the dev portal!
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,
    ]
});

client.login("bot tk");

const { Captcha } = require("discord.js-captcha");

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Bot opérationnel");
});

const captcha = new Captcha(client, {
    roleID: "role id", //optional
    channelID: "channel id", //optional
    sendToTextChannel: true, //optional, defaults to false
    addRoleOnSuccess: true, //optional, defaults to true. whether you want the bot to add the role to the user if the captcha is solved
    kickOnFailure: true, //optional, defaults to true. whether you want the bot to kick the user if the captcha is failed
    caseSensitive: true, //optional, defaults to true. whether you want the captcha responses to be case-sensitive
    attempts: 3, //optional, defaults to 1. number of attempts before captcha is considered to be failed
    timeout: 300000, //optional, defaults to 60000. time the user has to solve the captcha on each attempt in milliseconds
    showAttemptCount: true, //optional, defaults to true. whether to show the number of attempts left in embed footer
    customPromptEmbed: new EmbedBuilder(), //customise the embed that will be sent to the user when the captcha is requested
    customSuccessEmbed: new EmbedBuilder(), //customise the embed that will be sent to the user when the captcha is solved
    customFailureEmbed: new EmbedBuilder(), //customise the embed that will be sent to the user when they fail to solve the captcha
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    //in your bot application in the dev portal, make sure you have intents turned on!
    captcha.present(member); //captcha is created by the package, and sent to the member
});

captcha.on("success", data => {
    console.log(`Un membre a réussie le captcha !`);
    console.log(data);
});

captcha.on("failure", data => {
    console.log(`Un membre a raté le captcha !`);
    console.log(data);
});
```

Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the code is working correctly and you want to remove this particular warning, create an environment variable.

`.env` file at the root of your project:

```
NODE_NO_WARNINGS=1
```

Answer (score 0):

That error refers to your node.js particularly, this is warning regarding node.js that feature may change or be removed in future of node.js and it's not stable.

You can ignore the warning as it's experimental feature related only but you can suppress it by doing `process.noDeprecation = true;` in top of your file where this is causing mainly.